# How to write a dynamic query and How to use the dynamic query result in farther query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

```
                Table-1

                  Name      Months        Downtime
                    Lalonde     Jan-18        20.00
                    Lalonde     Feb-18       10.00
                    Lalonde     Mar-18       50.00
                    Lalonde     Apr-18       60.00
                    Lalonde     May-18       30.00
                    Lalonde     Jun-18       NULL
                    Lalonde     July-18      NULL
                    Lalonde     Aug-18       80.00
                    Lalonde     Sep-18       08.00
                    Lalonde     Oct-18       04.00
                    Lalonde     Nov-18      2.00
                    Lalonde     Dec-18      40.00
                    Lalonde     Jan-19      6.00
                    Lalonde     Feb-19      2.00
                    Lalonde     Mar-19      40.00

            Table-2

            Month       Incident    Issues      Name
            Jan-18      2       High      Lalonde
            Feb-18      10      High     Lalonde
            Mar-18      5       Critical Lalonde
            Apr-18      4       High     Lalonde
            May-18      2       Critical Lalonde
            June-18     10      High     Lalonde
            July-18     4       High      Lalonde
            Aug-18      3       High     Lalonde

            Sep-18      5       Critical Lalonde
            Oct-18      5       High     Lalonde
            Nov-18      1       Critical Lalonde
            Dec-18      5       High     Lalonde
            Jan-19      5       High     Lalonde
            Feb-19      1       Critical Lalonde
            Mar-19      5       High     Lalonde
```

Note:- Please note that  Month values are Dynamic they are not constant values.

**ExpectedOutPut:-1**

**Formula**=Table1/Table2=Downtime/Incidents

```
Names Issues Jan-18 feb-18 mar-18 Apr-18 So on to-Dec -18 Jan -19 Feb-19  Mar-19

Lalonde Critical 10   1    12.5  values  --- so on------ values here------
```

**Note**:-Here consider the output of ExpectedOutPut:1

```
ExpectedOutPut:-2 (On considering result  ExpectedOutPut:1)

Formula=Jan-19+Feb-19+March-19/3   
YTD 2019= Result
```

**Note**:-Here consider the output of ExpectedOutPut:1

```
ExpectedOutPut:-3(On considering result ExpectedOutPut:)

 Formula=Jan-18+Mar-18+Aug-18-----------Dec-18so on /12

YTD 2018= Result
```

Comment: And what's the DBMS?

Comment: Unless you have an extremely pressing reason otherwise, don't do this.  SQL isn't designed for dynamic numbers of columns, don't fight it.  Pivot the data in your application / report / whatever is consuming the data.

Comment: Sql server 2014